# Matlab: How to plot matrix A vs Matrix B?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I know that there is some similar questions but they doesn't answer my question.

I have many matrices in the same size, n and m is 64. 
Matrix A is the change at temperature between different locations and B is the distance between the locations. I want to plot the temperature difference vs distance. 
How do I know that example: element(11,23) in A is plotted against the same position i matrix B?

Do i just use `scatter(X(:),Y(:))` or `plot(X(:),Y(:))` ?

Comment: Yes, I believe those are the appropriate functions to use.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed,

```
scatter(A(:), B(:));
```

will plot what you want, i.e. temp. difference against distance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I asked a friend and was told that i cant plot matrix A vs B but, I can plot the colums against each other. By using a loop I got around the problem very easy.

```
for i=1:64
for j=1:64
scatter(Distance(i,j),Temperature(i,j))
hold on
end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: That is a very primitive way of doing the task! You are better off using `scatter(Distance(:),Temperature(:))` . That is the appropriate way of doing the thing in vectorized manner!